# Filter out Country with Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, spatial

is there any posibility to show only Germany Country Borders and inner Data with Mapbox ?

I dont want the rest of the world displayed.

Thankx,

Markus

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the Germany GeoJSON from http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/. Upload it as a dataset, export it to tilesets, and then to a map as a layer. Delete all other layers.